# Flutter: How to share PDF file to built inn apps like Whatsapp or email

Tags: file, flutter, share

I am developing an product information app, I need to share the spec PDF of the products, is there any way to do it. I use the package `share_extend` but while using this getting an exception

```
E/flutter (11283): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel com.zt.shareextend/share_extend)
E/flutter (11283): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:7)
```

This is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: 'Share File',
        onPressed: () async {


          var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          File file = File('${dir.path}/${widget.product}.pdf');

          if (!await file.exists()) {
            await file.create(recursive: true);
            file.writeAsStringSync("test for share documents file");
          }

          ShareExtend.share(file.path, "file");


        },
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffECECEC),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.share,
          color: Color(0xff6F6F6F),
          size: 30.0,
        ),
      ),);
}
```

Comment: add some code on how youre sharing the data

Comment: @Ggriffo I had updated my code.

Comment: found this issue from plugin repo https://github.com/zhouteng0217/ShareExtend/issues/14

Comment: [update] take away from issue chat  flutter clean then get packages, upgrade packages,

Comment: It doesn't work, I removed it. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 7):

You can now use the [Share plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/share) to do so!

ex:

```
Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/yourPdf.pdf'], text: 'Your PDF!');
```

Comment: this plugin discontinued now . anyother method for share pdf file ?